# Error while Integrating Vdocipher with Flutter. Caused by: android.view.InflateException

Tags: flutter

I am trying to integrate Vdocipher with flutter using the following code as mentioned in the official documentation

```
  Container(
              child: VdoPlayer(
                embedInfo: embedInfo,
                onPlayerCreated: onplayerCreated,
                onError: onError,
              ),
            )
```

I am always getting this error

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #206 in com.gmatpoint.app:layout/vdo_control_view_theme: Binary XML file line #206 in com.gmatpoint.app:layout/vdo_control_view_theme: Error inflating class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton

Thanks in advance

At present I am using 2.4.5 Vdocipher version. I even tried to downgrade the version I am using.The official code taken from github is working fine. But what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: Actually I got the issue resolved by adding the line
 <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
in android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml

But now there is another issue an action bar is getting added above the page 
and is reflecting in all other pages also